# Monoidal Equivalence: Two Definitions

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory, monoidal-categories

One has the definition of a monoidal equivalence as in *definition 12* of Baez's [Some Definitions Everyone Should Know](http://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/qg-winter2001/definitions.pdf).

I have also seen monoidal equivalence defined as a monoidal functor between monoidal categories which defines an equivalence (i.e. a fully faithful, essentially surjective functor) in the sense of *definition 5* in Baez (link above).

I wanted to double-check that these two definitions are distinct. If anybody has any intuitive insight as to why/when the two are employed, that would also be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: According to the comments on this question, they are actually equivalent : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2563128/monoidal-equivalence-is-a-monoidal-functor-that-is-also-an-equivalence-of-categ

Comment: A priori they're distinct but I wouldn't be surprised to find out they're the same (like the two definitions of equivalence)

Comment: Thanks, according to the discussion in the link above the two are equivalent. To show it apparently isn't difficult, yet requires quite some time and effort. An official source vouching for their equivalence is Remark 2.4.10 in http://www-math.mit.edu/~etingof/egnobookfinal.pdf